# How to wait until one list of calls are done to call the following ones

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java

I'm using `rxJava` and I want to do a `forEach` of a list, and for every item, make a call, and then once those calls are finished, call another one.

This is my code

```
val flowableList = answerListCreated.map {
        questionService.addAnswerToQuestion(
            questionId,
            it.id,
            MyUtils.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage(context = mContext!!)
        )
    }
    disposable = Flowable.concat(flowableList)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            addCorrectsAnswersToQuestion(questionId)
        }
```

But it's joining in the `subscribe` twice, and it should join in the subscribe once.

What I'm missing? I thought concat should be a good option because I've read that it does first the first job, and then when job1 is finished it starts the job2.

Well, also if necessary I can return `Observable<T>`, from now in my service I'm returning `Flowable<T>` to test this.

Comment: Use `map` to chain Observables

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to do something like:

```
val disposable = Flowable.fromArray(answerListCreated)
    .flatMap {
        questionService.addAnswerToQuestion(
            questionId,
            it.id,
            MyUtils.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage(context = mContext!!)
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
    .toList()
    .subscribe {
        addCorrectsAnswersToQuestion(questionId)
    }
```